Testing significance of difference between distance matrices
In microbial studies one often looks at beta-diversity in terms of a PCoA decomposition of a distance matrix between the samples, e.g.:

(image source)
This usually serve to draw various conclusions (which are then tested using other methods) as to, e.g., whether the treatment significantly changes a microbial composition or whether there are significant differences between healthy and sick individuals.
The visual impressions however can be very misleading, especially in presence of error ellipses. I wonder, if there are statistical tests applicable directly to distance matrices or the lowest PCoA components, to determine if the differences between two groups are significant.
The distance metrics used for calculation of distance matrices are usually non-euclidean (such as Beay-curtis, UniFrac distance, Aitchison distance, etc.) - hence the use of PCoA (rather than PCA.)
